# All section headers in uitableview are in the same spot

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UIView which I want to be able to reuse throughout my application as a section header in tableviews. Here is the applicable code for that (this is basically all it is doing):

```
-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _title = title;
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-%@-[_titleLabel]-%@-|", HORIZONTAL_SPACE, HORIZONTAL_SPACE] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self, _titleLabel)]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-%@-[_titleLabel]-%@-|", VERTICAL_SPACE, VERTICAL_SPACE] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self, _titleLabel)]];
        [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    }
    return self; 
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *headerText = _headers[section];
    if(headerText.length){
        AWSmallTextSectionHeader *header = [[AWSmallTextSectionHeader alloc] initWithTitle:headerText];
        return header;
    }
    return [UIView new];
}
```

The problem is that when the views draw to the screen they all start at the same origin...This is what is looks like at the top of the tableview:

[image: overlapping section headers]

It is really weird though because it is acting as if it is in the correct section, for example, if you start scrolling and one of the sections go offscreen, the view that corresponds to that section header will disappear.

I have a feeling it has to do with the way I am adding my constraints but I am not sure.

Thanks

**Edit** (this is also implemented)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
    heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == SECTION_INDEX_PHONE) {
        return  60.f; //CGRectGetHeight(self.phoneSectionHeader.frame);
    } else if (section == SECTION_INDEX_FEEDBACK) {
        return 40.f; //CGRectGetHeight(self.feedbackSectionHeader.frame);
    }
return 5.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;` was the problem.

Once I got rid of that it was working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Should you at some point set the bounds for the header section view?

Also ensure you're adapting the heightForHeaderInSection:

```
This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.
```

Comment: like width/height constraints?

Comment: or the Bounds directly?

Comment: Perhaps. I'll be honest, layout in VFL is greek to me, but at some point that view has to know how high and wide it's gotta be. Right now _titleLabel has its H and V constraints but nothing to say it's gotta be a certain height or width. and width, it appears.

Comment: Perhaps w/h constraints or bounds directly.

Comment: Well bounds *should* be out of the question because of autolayout. But this actually has nothing to do with the height or width of header. It is actually the origin that is wrong. The widths and heights are actually calculated correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have probably said that I am also implmenting that method. Editing my question @BrooksHanes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61709/discussion-between-brooks-hanes-and-dostrander).